# Socket vs HTTP for mobile application

Tags: android, ios, sockets, http, mobile

I am developing native mobile application ( Android, iOS ) with some VoIP and social network functionality. So the main parts of the overall applications are:

1. Mobile app
2. SIP Server ( for VoIP )
3. Web Server

Given that:

- there is already persistent socket connection ( for VoIP )
- the Web Server can send some messages to the mobile app ( via SIP Server ) and vice versa

What is the best way of communication  between mobile app and the web server, when the mobile application is in the foreground and user browses some social network functionality ( Like viewing images, texts, messages ). Mobile battery, performance, reliability, scalability and the development ease are the issues.

Currently I can think of three ways:

1) HTTP request/response - traditional & reliable programming. In order to retrieve some data mobile app will need to make a http request ( and establish new connection ).
But I am afraid, that this can kill the mobile battery.

2) When the mobile app goes to foreground - open a socket to the web server. All interactions between mobile app and the web server will use this socket. When app goes to background - socket is closed. ( So two open sockets - in foreground, one in background, i.e only VoIP signaling socket stays )

3) Use the VoIP signaling socket for everything. In this case the SIP server will be a mediator between a mobile app and web server, of course the SIP server might become a bottleneck.

Comment: Why do you think HTTP will affect battery life but sockets won't?

Comment: The first option establish a new connection every time application requests some data ( i.e user check a facebook-like wall - a new connection to get the data, user checks messages - new connection to get the data, user writes a message to wall - new connection to send the data )

The second option - uses one connection and just sends request/response information using this connection.

I am not professional mobile developer, but I think that establishing new connection - will drain the battery much more, than  when you have only one connection.